# What is the point of having "logout" endpoint in django-rest-auth?

Tags: django, rest, authentication, django-rest-auth

I [this](https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/) article I have read that token based authentication is stateless, meaning that the servers don't keep record of logged in users.

On the other hand in the [django-rest-auth API docs](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_endpoints.html#basic) there is a logout endpoint mentioned. What is it for?

Comment: Old question... but it's because if you use their SessionMiddleware, Django does not use token based authentication, they store information for logged in users.

Answer (score 5):

During log out, the authentication token issued to the user is deleted. You can check out the [logout source](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/views.py#L121) where it calls `request.user.auth_token.delete()`. Therefore, the next time the user logs in, a new token will be issued.

Comment: Is this really true? I'm just trying to implement the logout functionality using this package, but after successfully logout, the token remains in the db and I can still access the page if I put the 'Token soCalledDeletedToken' in the request header.

Comment: I had a similar problem. Turns out, I didn't have authentication globally enabled. So, when I was calling `logout`, even though I included the credentials, it was being handled as an anonymous user. Therefore, the token of the actual user was not deleted. Hope this helps,

Comment: @Demetris How do you globally enable authentication? I have configured the authentication scheme as explained in the docs (see link at the end), looks like that's what you mean, right? But still my token is not deleted on logout. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme

Comment: @RikSchoonbeek Yes that is what I was referring to. Set the `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` to `rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication`.

Comment: It's also necessary to namespace `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` to `REST_FRAMEWORK`.

Comment: If I explicitly add the token in my header during the logout call it seems to work. I can't then retrieve the user for example using the same token

Comment: @GerryDevine Certainly more information is needed. Create a new question and the community may be able to help out. Good luck!

Comment: Demetris - I wasn't really asking a question. Just pointing out that when I attach my token to the logout request headers, it will explicitly log out the user (i.e delete the token on the server) - which I thought might help @Rik 's issue above. Correct me if I am wrong though. Cheers

Comment: @Demetris comment helped me, adding the class made deleting the token possible, also I was passing a token object in the header and not the actual string.

Answer (score 0):

In the event you are using the JWT option with django-rest-auth, the logout behavior doesn't actually appear to delete the JWT tokens.  So it seems to be essentially doing nothing.  Now I'm still new to JWT, but based on what I've learned - it appears that this isn't even necessary.  So just delete on the client and you'll be okay.   Still it would be nice to have a JUST-DESTROY-THE-JWT-TOKEN-BECAUSE-WHO-NEEDS-POTENTIALLY-UNEXPIRED-DANGEROUS-STUFF-HANGING-AROUND option.  But sadly, I don't think rest_framework_jwt supports this.

rest_framework_simplejwt (https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt) does seem to support this "blacklisting" which is promising! (rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist)  And yet, alas rest_auth does not support simplejwt, straight up - ah well.  If someone figures out how to do this, I'd be game.

But back to what's going on with rest-auth's jwt implementation...

So when you are logging out, it does attempt to delete the django token, but I don't believe that's what you are doing here since you should have the following in your settings.py if you are using the JSONWebTokenAuthentication class:

**settings.py (for JWT)**

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication', # USED BY JWT.
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication', # IGNORED BY JWT
)
```

Now when django-rest-auth goes to execute /logout, let's see what they are doing from their source code on https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/views.py

**views.py (from rest-auth source)**

```
from django.contrib.auth import (
    login as django_login,
    logout as django_logout
)

from .models import TokenModel


#-------snip-------


class LogoutView(APIView):
    """
    Calls Django logout method and delete the Token object
    assigned to the current User object.
    Accepts/Returns nothing.
    """
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if getattr(settings, 'ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET', False):
            response = self.logout(request)
        else:
            response = self.http_method_not_allowed(request, *args, **kwargs)

        return self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.logout(request)

    def logout(self, request):
        try:
            request.user.auth_token.delete()
        except (AttributeError, ObjectDoesNotExist):
            pass
        if getattr(settings, 'REST_SESSION_LOGIN', True):
            django_logout(request)

        response = Response({"detail": _("Successfully logged out.")},
                            status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        if getattr(settings, 'REST_USE_JWT', False):
            from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings as jwt_settings
            if jwt_settings.JWT_AUTH_COOKIE:
                response.delete_cookie(jwt_settings.JWT_AUTH_COOKIE)
return response
```

**models.py (from rest-auth source)**

```
from django.conf import settings

from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token as DefaultTokenModel

from .utils import import_callable

# Register your models here.

TokenModel = import_callable(
getattr(settings, 'REST_AUTH_TOKEN_MODEL', DefaultTokenModel))
```

So unless you've set the REST_AUTH_TOKEN_MODEL attribute in your settings to a custom token model (see https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/docs/configuration.rst - which is doubtful, let's all be honest here.  Who is doing this...), then it's just trying to delete the DefaultTokenModel - which is the django_token/session authentication model we aren't using.

I do hope things migrate to simplejwt as it's much more actively supported.

And I also hope this brain-dump/jwt digging helps someone.

P.S.  A little more on JWT, optimal uses and blacklisting.  https://dev.to/_arpy/how-to-log-out-when-using-jwt-4ajm